# How to implement Google Analytics explicity in Google sites?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics

I have a Google site in which I have a gadget which sends data to Google Analytics using its send method which is written in the javascript of my Google gadget.

I am able to see the data in my User Explorer of Google Analytics. I get a "Review permission" button on my Google sites page which I find very annoying. It adds the gadget to the list of user's authorized apps which the user can easily delete and hence the user wont be tracked. I need some custom parameters to be extracted from Google sites while the user is browsing my website.

A better option was to provide an add-on. However, due to Google's restriction on Javascript that was not possible.

Is there any better way to do get user analytics. If so, please suggest.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programing related may be better suited for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DalmTo It is related to programming concept. Please find the question at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/101608/how-to-implement-google-analytics-explicity-in-google-sites as you find it suitable and answer.